# Can't install colorama in termux

Tags: python, openssl, termux, colorama

[image]
When I tried to execute the command "pip install colorama" to install the colorama package, I encountered an error message indicating that I needed to install SSL. However, when I attempted to install SSL, it didn't seem to do anything.

Comment: I cannot reproduce the error, have you tried to install the colorama package inside of a conda environment?

Comment: Please, never use images of text when the text can be posted instead. As a new user here, please also take the [tour] and read [ask]. Further, search for the error message! In many cases, people reported similar errors already and you can find solutions. That said, you don't have a programming problem here but one with system administration. Trying to run `sudo ...` without understanding is one part of the problem. Consider e.g. superuser.com for that questions category instead.

Comment: you dont need sudo to install packages in termux. did you leave out the output of pkg installs or is there no output ? Try apt install, and even go read the termux wiki/docs to learn more. You might have a broken install too. Try to upgrade and apt fix broken.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you can't simply run sudo in termux unless your device is rooted. Second, it says can't find a version that satisfies, not anything about permission denied.
Try running apt update && apt upgrade
From there, then try pip install colorama